# Параметризированный SQL-скрипт Delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac

Задача- на форме в Edit-е ввожу имя роли и хочу создать новую роль бд параметризированным SQL скриптом, компононт FDScript. :

```
with Fmain.FDScript1 do begin
 SQLScripts.Clear;
 SQLScripts.Add;
 with SQLScripts[0].SQL do begin
   Add('VARIABLE Rolename CHAR='+editRoleName.Text);
   Add('create role :Rolename');
 end;
 ValidateAll;
 ExecuteAll;
```

или так (создаю параметр Param[0] компонента FDScript ):

```
with Fmain.FDScript1 do begin
 SQLScripts.Clear;
 SQLScripts.Add;
 with SQLScripts[0].SQL do begin
   Add('create role :Rolename');
   Fmain.FDScript1.Params[0].AsString:=editRoleName.Text; 
 end;
 ValidateAll;
 ExecuteAll;
```

но выводит:

> EIBNativeException with message [FireDac][phys][FB] Dinamic Sql error
>   error code=-104 Token unknown line1, column 13 ?

как-будто всё делаю по-примеру:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Executing_SQL_Scripts_(FireDAC)
 to define and use parameters, use the following code:

```
with FDScript1.SQLScripts[0].SQL do begin
  Add('VARIABLE name CHAR IN = ''aaa''');
  Add('VARIABLE id NUMBER INOUT');
  Add('INSERT INTO master (name) VALUES (:name) RETURNING id {INTO :id};');
  Add('INSERT INTO detail (fk_id, name) VALUES (:id, ''bbb'');');
end;
```

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет сейчас доступа к Firebird, но могу предположить, что дело в одинарных кавычках, потому что параметр передается как строка, т.е. получается запрос create role 'User_role', а должно быть create role User_role. Поэтому, вместо параметра, можно попробовать Add('create role ' + editRoleName.Text);

Comment: Не знаю как в FireDAC, но в стандартном `TADOQuery` параметрам нужно задавать имена, чтобы они работали. Что-то типа `with Fmain.FDScript1.Params.Add do begin Name := 'Rolename'; AsString := editRoleName.Text; end;`

Comment: Кавычки еще должны быть. Так должно работать. `'VARIABLE Rolename CHAR='+QuotedStr(editRoleName.Text)` А в целом нужно использовать параметры, тогда все должно работать как часы.

Comment: так работает: with SQLScripts[0].SQL do begin
   Add('create role '+editRoleName.Text);
      end;
А параметром или переменным как написать правильный код пока остаётся загадкой.

Answer (score 1):

Не работал с этой библиотекой, но предполагаю, что:

Имя роли нельзя передать через параметр. Используйте вместо Params Macros или Arguments.

```
with Fmain.FDScript1 do 
  begin
  s := editRoleName.Text;
  Arguments.Clear;
  Arguments.Add(s);    
  SQLScripts.Clear;
  SQLScripts.Add;
  SQLScripts[0].SQL.Add('create role &1;');
 end;
```

Но обязательно проверьте сначала что s является корректным идентификатором, чтобы исключить sql-инъекцию. Т. к. в данном способе просто меняется текст запроса (что вы могли бы и вручную сделать). В отличие от Params, которые используют механизм параметров Firebird.